# iOS - Images not loading on reusable UICollectionViewCell's

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hello I have a problem that I would greatly appreciate any help if possible. I have an app that has a UICollectionView which uses a UICollectionViewCell that has an UIImageView inside of it. This image view is supposed to be set each time the cell is generated with it's appropriate image. However the image does not come out, if I do an initWithImage on the image view with the data of the image that i'm trying to set works but then each time the cell is reused that new image view stays there.

Here is the code:

```
@interface collectionViewController : UICollectionViewController
```

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView; 
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *imageURLs;

@end

@interface collectionViewController () 
    @property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *cachedImage;

@end


@implementation collectionViewController

@synthesize imageURLs = _imageURLs; @synthesize cachedImage =_cachedImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     // Register reusable cell for controller
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[collectionViewCell class]  forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Image Cell"];

    //Set url for images
    _imageURLs = [@[@"http://www.bestcssvault.com/installation/wpcontent/themes/cssvault/gallery/2012/02/daniel_designer-265x180.jpg",
                @"http://www.bestcssvault.com/installation/wp-content/themes/cssvault/gallery/2012/02/595x400hngry-265x180.png",
                @"http://www.bestcssvault.com/installation/wp-content/themes/cssvault/gallery/2012/02/licron-265x180.jpg",
                @"http://www.bestcssvault.com/installation/wp-content/themes/cssvault/gallery/2012/02/media-265x180.jpg",
                @"http://www.bestcssvault.com/installation/wp-content/themes/cssvault/gallery/2012/02/alio-265x180.jpg",
                @"http://www.bestcssvault.com/installation/wp-content/themes/cssvault/gallery/2012/02/zdravkomecava-265x180.jpg",
                @"http://www.bestcssvault.com/installation/wp-content/themes/cssvault/gallery/2011/12/guidepiscine_dot_com-265x180.jpg",
                @"http://www.bestcssvault.com/installation/wp-content/themes/cssvault/gallery/2011/12/web6-265x180.jpg",
                @"http://www.bestcssvault.com/installation/wp-content/themes/cssvault/gallery/2011/12/CSSVault_Transics-thumb-265x180.jpg",
                @"http://www.bestcssvault.com/installation/wp-content/themes/cssvault/gallery/2011/12/screen3-265x180.jpg",
                @"http://www.bestcssvault.com/installation/wp-content/themes/cssvault/gallery/2011/12/divaoffice595x400-265x180.jpg",
                @"http://www.bestcssvault.com/installation/wp-content/themes/cssvault/gallery/2011/12/screenshot-265x180.jpg"] mutableCopy]; }

    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
        return 1; 
    }

    -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return _imageURLs.count; 
    }

    -(collectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Image Cell";
        collectionViewCell *imageCollectionCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        int row = [indexPath row];

        if(imageCollectionCell.imageCollectionView) NSLog(@"worked at %d", row);

        //Get Image Data
        NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_imageURLs[row]];

        dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("image downloader", NULL);
        dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
        NSData * imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImage * imageCompleted = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
            imageCollectionCell.inspirationImage = imageCompleted;
            //imageCollectionCell.imageCollectionView.image = imageCompleted;
            //NSLog(@"width = %f, height = %f", imageCompleted.size.width, imageCompleted.size.height);
        });
    });
    imageCollectionCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];    //dispatch_release(downloadQueue);

    return imageCollectionCell; 
}
@end

@interface collectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell 
    @property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageCollectionView; 
    @property (weak,nonatomic) UIImage *inspirationImage; 
@end

@implementation collectionViewCell 
    @synthesize imageCollectionView =_imageCollectionView; 
    @synthesize inspirationImage = _inspirationImage;

-(void)setImageCollectionView:(UIImageView *)imageCollectionView{
    //imageCollectionView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    //[self.contentView addSubview:imageCollectionView];
    if(!_imageCollectionView){
         _imageCollectionView = imageCollectionView;
    }
    _imageCollectionView.image = _inspirationImage; }

-(void)setInspirationImage:(UIImage *)inspirationImage {
    if(!_inspirationImage){
        _inspirationImage = inspirationImage;
    }
    //_imageCollectionView.image = inspirationImage;
    self.imageCollectionView.image = _inspirationImage; }


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return self; 
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    //_inspirationImage = [[UIImage alloc] init]; 
}


/* // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing. // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code 
}
*/
@end
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in UIImageView. If ImageView has nil image when the cell has been presented it will not be shown when you set image. There are 2 solutions.
1) Set default image when you create cell.

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Image Cell";
collectionViewCell *imageCollectionCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImage * placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];
imageCollectionCell.inspirationImage = placeholderImage;
```

2) Call setNeedsLayout on cell after updating image.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImage * imageCompleted = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
            imageCollectionCell.inspirationImage = imageCompleted;
[cell setNeedsLayout];
```

Comment: I have tried implementing your method but I still only get a grey UICollectionViewCell, any other ideas by any chance? Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: This is strange because I've tested this code on my UItableViewController. I've used standard UITableViewCell and old implementation for getting reusable cell. So maybe it's something wrong wit that

Comment: I dont think that testing on UITableViewController relates to this scenario. Do you mea that the reason being both reuses the same view again and again, I dont have this problem with table view but every time I use collectionview I have the same problem again and again. I could send you the project for both tableview and collectionview if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have another approach for this.

Asynchronously download images into another array of image data first.

Then inside `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, just check if that image is downloaded (maybe if not yet, set to nil; downloaded replace the nil to the image data)

If it is downloaded, set the image, else set to another "default" image.

You might also need references to the image view so that you can update the image when an image is downloaded.

Comment: I have tried this as well and setting the image to nil makes it not appear still in the view, I have to do an alloc init to get it to work and that has been so far the only way but it is very unreliable and inefficient. Any other ideas will be greatly appreciated it.